# if a cell contains specific text then return value from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In EXCEL I would like to use a formula that would read what is in cell A1 and then return a specific drop down list (already created in another sheet).

Example:

IF The cell A1 contains the number "1.1" Then in cell B1 I want to return a drop down list of 5 different choices that is already created in another sheet.

example pic:
[image: example pic]

Comment: Can you post an example of your input and what you think the output should look like? It sounds like you want to set up data validation from a list in B1, but have it vary which list is used based on A1

Comment: And what happens if A1 contains something other than 1.1?

Comment: For example, in A1 we have: "1.1. Chapter" and in A2 we have: "2.5 Chapter" Then what I want is from a list (as shown in column D) in B1 cell somehow only the options that matches the same chapter "1.1" will shown. Meaning 1.1.1 - 1.1.6 and respectively, in B2 only the options 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3 will shown. That way the user could not enter e.g. in B1 any option that is not starts with 1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a conditional drop down menu in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1313305/creating-a-conditional-drop-down-menu-in-excel)

Answer (score -1):

IF(SEARCH might help.  Please see the image below for the idea.

[image]

Comment: These two answers don't really address what was asked in the question.  The OP appears to want to select a drop down list based on A1, and the criterion is A1=1.1 rather than A1 contains 1.1.

Answer (score -1):

It the example above i showed it being done directly, but it can also be done with referenced cells. The cells being searched don't only need to contain the searched value, but it can be part of a longer string. See the next answer for the image

[image]